# Database performance using mysqlslap vs actual sql queries

Tags: php, mysql, performance, benchmarking

We are benchmarking a number of servers with a view to migrating our current site.

We have tested 2 configs against the current setup, using a mysqlslap test and by running sql queries on table with same data and measuring using php microtime. The mysqlslap tests are as follows:

- Current: 4.977 seconds
- Config 1: 2.988 seconds
- Config 2: 1.786 seconds

However am I puzzled by the results from the microtime results, as the current server is fastest in all but one of the tests. The current server appears to be faster when running smaller queries and slower for the large query. This is an example of one of the benchmark cases (just in case I'm doing something stupid!):

```
$t1 = microtime(TRUE);
for($i=1; $i<10; $i++)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT a.ref, a.code, a.expiry
                FROM payment a
                WHERE a.Amount >0
                    AND a.type = "card"
                    AND a.user_id = '.$i.'
                    AND a.result = "success"
                    AND a.amount > 0
                    AND a.code = (SELECT b.code
                                        FROM payment b
                                        WHERE b.user_id = a.user_id
                                        AND b.type="Card"
                                        AND b.amount > 0
                                        ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
                                        )
                ORDER BY a.date DESC LIMIT 1';
    mysql_query($sql);
}
$t2 = microtime(TRUE);
$t = $t2-$t1;
echo $t.'s';
```

So I have two questions:

1. Are these expected results? With the current server coming top in the microtime test (faster for smaller queries, slower for larger queries) but bottom in the mysqlslap test.
2. Other than (sysbench) which we cannot install on the current server - could you suggest any other methods to benchmark the servers?

**Update**: I've run the same sql queries used in the microtime tests as custom queries via mysqlslap and now the new configs are much faster across the board. When running the microtime tests we were using the live database to check common requests - could it be that the results were already in memory?

Comment: sysbench beats the hell out of mysqlslap.  Why can't you get it installed?  bonnie++ is also awesome for benchmarking disk I/O, a critical component of database performance.

Comment: @Charles the old server uses an old flavor of FreeBSD and it's proving difficult to install sysbench. Bonnie++ looks good, thanks for the tip.